# Find replace string the doesn't matching the specific pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I have hundreds of files containing like the below. In my sqlldr ' is the text qualifier and my files are rejected due to text like `Wegman's` , which contains apostrophe in the text itself.

Using sed/awk is there a way to find such string and replace 's with ` tick or something?

```
t2.txt';'20160707071500';'478251533';'TWN';'20160620160801';'1';'691891-2';'2';'0';'Employer';'1';'OMCProcessed';'Wegman's Food Market';'';'Wegman's Food Markets';'14411364807'
```

One solution I thought is, find text that is not equal to '; but not sure how to put to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps here `sed` is a better alternative

```
$ sed -r 's/([^;])(\x27)([^;])/\1\2\2\3/g' file

't2.txt';'20160707071500';'478251533';'TWN';'20160620160801';'1';'6918912';'2';'0';'Employer';'1';'OMCProcessed';'Wegman''s Food Market';'';'Wegman''s Food Markets';'14411364807'
```

Comment: Nice. Maybe a bit more readable : `sed -r "s/([^;])'([^;])/\1''\2/" file
`.

Comment: @Kenavoz your solution is much simpler, but don't we have to add `/g` to replace global? `sed -r "s/([^;])'([^;])/\1\2/g" t1` this works me.

Comment: @Kenavoz, correct more readable, I'm trying to avoid double quoting  scripts for some reason, using the char code avoids single quote concatenation dance of the script.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to escape single quotes in SQL is to double them, but you can modify the call to `gsub` to replace them with whatever you like.

There's probably a fancier way to do this, but here I've simply stripped off the enclosing quotes from each field, replaced the interior quotes, and then assigned back to the original field with the enclosing quotes included again.

```
$ cat m.txt
't2.txt';'20160707071500';'478251533';'TWN';'20160620160801';'1';'691891-2';'2';'0';'Employer';'1';'OMCProcessed';'Wegman's Food Market';'';'Wegman's Food Markets';'14411364807'

$ cat m.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
        f = substr($i,2,(length($i) - 2))
        gsub("'", "''", f)
        $i = "'" f "'";
    }
}1

$ awk -f m.awk m.txt
't2.txt';'20160707071500';'478251533';'TWN';'20160620160801';'1';'691891-2';'2';'0';'Employer';'1';'OMCProcessed';'Wegman''s Food Market';'';'Wegman''s Food Markets';'14411364807'
```